# Prove that given $X\sim N(0,1)$, then $X^2 \sim \Gamma(1/2,1/2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a random variable of density $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} exp(-x^2 /2)$ and I want to prove that the distribution of $X^2$ is $\Gamma(1/2,1/2)= \frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)\sqrt{2}} x^{-1/2} exp(-x/2)$.

Now, given a variable $X$ there is a theorem for calculating the pdf of $h(X)$ when $h$ is a diffeomorphism. The problem is that here I do not have a diffeomorphism. Intuitively, though, it is clear that restricting to the positive numbers, you can use the theorem and then double the pdf you obtain (because for every $Y=X^2$ there are two equiprobable $X$ that give $Y$). Doing it this way solves the exercise. However, I was wondering, how do you do this in general?

I mean, in this case the probability of $X$ and $-X$ is the same, and intuition gives us the answer. But in general this is not the case. How should I proceed then? I would say that (given $Y=X^2$) I should divide the two cases
$X>0$ and $X<0$, treat them separately (using the fact that now I have a diffeomorphism on both of them) and then the pdf I was searching would be the sum of the two. Is this correct or there is some mistake I don't see?

Comment: Your approach is correct. In general when the transformation is not bijective, you can try to partition the domain into different regions such that the transformation is bijective in each of them, and thus you can apply the jacobian transformation for them individually, and then sum the resulting pdfs obtained in each region together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic strategy is right. The general method to derive the CDF of $X^2$ if you know the CDF of $X$ is:
$$  \mathbb P(X^2 \leq a) = \mathbb P(-\sqrt a \leq X \leq a) = \mathbb P(X \leq \sqrt a) - \mathbb P(X < -\sqrt a)$$
Thus, if you're dealing with a continuous r.v. $X$ that has CDF $F_X(a)$, the CDF of $X^2$ is therefore $F_{X^2}(a) = F_X(\sqrt a) - F_X(-\sqrt a)$ for all nonnegative $a$.

If your original $X$ is symmetric about $0$, then as you noted, things are a bit simpler because $F_X(\sqrt a) = -F_X(-\sqrt a)$, so the formula would reduce to $2 F_X(\sqrt a)$ -- but you can still work with the above method even if $X$ is not symmetric.